# Spring boot 2 custom favicon

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vue.js

I am doing a spring boot project with VueJS frontend and want to use a favicon from Vue project. Dist folder is copied via maven to the resources dir

> /src/main/resources/public

Favicon from there is not read.

Comment: `Favicon from there is not read.`  What error does it fail with ? How are you reading the favicon? Please add some details

Comment: From the dir I have mentioned. There is no error message only empty favicon in browser

Comment: Open developer console in the browser. and check is there any error there.